# WordPress Custom Posts - Remove Base slug

Tags: wordpress

I want my custom posts url to be: `website.com/post-name`;

I have function to create Custom Post Type:

```
function create_posttype() {
register_post_type( 'credit-cards',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Credit Cards' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'credit_cards' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'credit-cards','with_front' => false),
      'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'excerpt' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

With `'with_front' => false` i was expecting that it will hide `credit-cards` from url. 
For some reason, that doesn't affect my url.

How can i hide `credit-cards` from slug?

Comment: Please use filter post_type_link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the filter(`post_type_link`) to remove the custom post type base slug from URL. Put this code in the `functions.php` file.

```
function remove_base_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'custom_post_type' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'remove_base_slug', 10, 3 );
```

If you get 404 error then you should this script in `functions.php` also.

```
function check_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'custom_post_type', 'page' ) );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'check_parse_request' );
```

**Note:** `custom_post_type` can be `books`, `events`, `blogs` etc.

Comment: Thank you, but For some reason i get 404 error .. What' the reason? Tried to save permalinks, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please change permalink from admin panel

Comment: Hey, @Rost, please see my updated anwser. I have tested it. It's working fine